# Não consigo imprimir, na função main, valores provenientes de um vetor criado em outra função recebido por um ponteiro duplo

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

O código-fonte a seguir é a miniaturização de um problema maior no qual estou trabalhando e já faz dois dias que não consigo resolver o problema.

Preciso imprimir os valores do vetor gerado pela função "fazVetor", na função "main".

Porém, para que o código se assemelhe ao problema real no qual estou trabalhando, existem duas restrições que devem ser respeitadas. Estas estão comentadas no código a seguir.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 3

int fazVetor(int **vet){
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * TAM);

    array[0] = 4;
    array[1] = 7;
    array[2] = 8;

    /* nesta função somente a linha a seguir PODE ser alterada. */
    *vet = array;
}

int main()
{
    int **qq;

    /* Na função main, somente a linha a seguir NÃO PODE ser alterada. */
    fazVetor(&qq);

    printf("\n--==[Valores do Vetor]==--\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf(" %d", (qq[i]));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

O código acima funciona, mas não da maneira que deveria. Ou seja, não consigo imprimir os três valores do vetor. Quando muito, consigo imprimir endereços de memória.

Se alguém puder ajudar, será de grande valia!

Comment: Quais as linhas que podem ser alteradas ? A assinatura da função não joga com o tipo passado. `fazVetor(&qq)` não joga com `int fazVetor(int **vet){` e uma delas terá que ser alterada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na função `main`, a variável `qq` está declarada como ponteiro duplo e, ao chamar a função `fazVetor()` com o operador `&qq`, gera um ponteiro triplo.

Como a função `fazVetor()` recebe um ponteiro duplo, isso gera o erro ao imprimir o conteúdo do vetor.

A solução é alterar a declaração da variável `qq` para ponteiro simples (com apenas um `*`):

```
int *qq;
```

Após esta alteração, o resultado é impresso corretamente:

```
--==[Valores do Vetor]==--

 4 7 8
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado!